# Why are "mobile" and "automobile" pronounced differently?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I just came across the words and then I looked them both up in the dictionary app, which shows the word "mobile" pronounces as /'məʊbaɪl/, whereas the other word-"automobile", which ends with the same spelt "mobile" pronounces as /'ɔːtəməbiːl/? I'm not sure if this "mobile" word pronounces differently as shown in the app or they actually pronounce the same?

Comment: They're pronounced differently as described. You'll notice that the noun "mobile" doesn't mean what "-mobile" means in the noun "automobile," like if "automobile" were really "auto mobile." Also, you'll find a lot of words that actually are forms of each other do change when adding a suffix or prefix, like "pathological" is pronounced "path-o-LO-gi-cal," whily "pathology" is pronounced "pa-THO-log-y," not "pa-tho-LO-gy."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - actually *-mobile* in *automobile* is derived from *mobile (adjective).* https://www.etymonline.com/word/automobile

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: The pathology-pathological variation is because of English stress patterns.

Comment: In the US I've always heard the noun, referring to a piece of art dangling from strings, pronounced the same as the ending of *automobile*.

Comment: In American English the last syllable of both is identical /bil/, but the next-to-last (i.e, first) syllable in _mobile_ is stressed, and the vowel is tense back rounded /o/, while the next-to-last syllable in _automobile_ is unstressed, and the vowel is lax central unrounded /ə/. Nobody would ever confuse them.

Answer (score 5):

Because *mobile* entered English in the [15th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/mobile) and underwent the Great Vowel Shift (GVS). The GVS was a series of changes in the pronunciation of English vowels that took place between 1400 and 1700 [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift)]. It must have been pronounced with /iː/ and the GVS changed the vowel /iː/ to /aɪ/ (also see *bite*, which was pronounced the same as *beat* before the GVS).

*Automobile* on the other hand entered English [after the GVS](https://www.etymonline.com/word/automobile) and preserved its original vowel.

Comment: For some people it went through the GVS; for others it's a spelling pronunciation. It's been years since I heard any English speaker pronounce _mobile_ as /mobayl/. If I heard it now, I would expect it to refer to a  named object or event, with the very special pronunciation preserved in the name, in context.